# Why return expression in while loop doesn't work

Tags: c++

the code below is count int m can be consist by which number in array data, but the `return 0;` expression for exit doesn't work, it will occur stack corrupt, I have to use `exit(0);`, why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void increase(bool seq[], int size);

constexpr int n = 5;

int main()
{
    int m, data[n];
    bool seq[n];
    std::cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> data[i];
        seq[i] = false;
    }
    while (true) {
        bool isEnd = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            if (!seq[i])
                isEnd = false;
        if (isEnd) {
            std::cout << "IMPOSSIBLE!!!";
            return 0;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            if (seq[i])
                sum += data[i];
        if (sum == m) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                if (seq[i])
                    std::cout << data[i] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        increase(seq, n);
    }
}

void increase(bool array[], int size)
{
    bool isCarry = true;
    for (int i = size; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (isCarry) {
            isCarry = array[i];
            array[i] = !array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which return statement do you mean? Can you mark it with a comment? Please provide a [mcve] containing input data. I can't reproduce the problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/29pLZtSmDOgtQ6oN

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean that `return 0;` after `std::cout << "IMPOSSIBLE!!!";` doesn't end the program? Do you see `"IMPOSSIBLE!!!"` printed?

Comment: If you replace `return 0` with `exit(0)`, it works?

Comment: You have undefined behavior in `increase` which writes past the end of the array.

Comment: Not the problem in this case but I'd recommend putting braces on all `if`s and `for` loops even when they aren't necessary to avoid potential bugs when modifying your code to add an extra line to a statement and forgetting to add braces

Comment: @LuketheGeek Yes, I want know why

Comment: @ThomasSablik The return statement in the if(sum == m) condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is incorrect

```
void increase(bool array[], int size)
{
    bool isCarry = true;
    for (int i = size; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (isCarry) {
            isCarry = array[i];
            array[i] = !array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

it should be

```
void increase(bool array[], int size)
{
    bool isCarry = true;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (isCarry) {
            isCarry = array[i];
            array[i] = !array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The valid indexes for an array of size N are 0 to N - 1 (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

It's controversial, but you can fix the issue in `increase` with

```
for (int i = size; i --> 0; /*intentionally blank*/){
```

This has the advantage that it also works with `unsigned` types. `-->` is the *slide operator* and, of course, is not really an operator at all, but is `--` followed by `>`.

Not all software houses allow it. I do. Perhaps that's because I'm more of a mathematical programmer and as I've grown up with this, I find it to be an idiomatic way of counting down to zero, particularly with `unsigned` types, as I think your `size` and `i` should be - and in that case `i >= 0` would always be `true`.

Comment: Well, I guess the controversial part is pretending the existence of such operator ;). A `(i--) > 0` condition should pass any review.

Comment: @Bob__ Notwithstanding the fact that `-->` is clear once you get used to it